# Generate jQuery like API-Documentation (not from sourcecode!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentation

I am currently writing a plugin for jQuery.
Now I wonder how I should create the documentation for this plugin as I guess that there are better ways than directly writing HTML.

However, I do not want to put my documentation into the sourcecode and thereby making finding the correct lines while debugging impossible. Thus, I am looking for a way to separate documentation and sourcecode.

How is the jQuery documentation generated? When looking into the jQuery sourcecode, I don't find any documentation annotations which makes me hope that I might be able to use the same system as they do.
Are the tools they use somehow documented?

I found the following XML-file while looking for an answer  http://api.jquery.com/api/ which seems to be generated sometime inside the "build"-process of jQuery.
I would be happy to write my documentation into a similar file and run some tools over it to "prettify" it for displaying it to the user.

How do you create your documentation for jQuery libaries (except putting it into the sourcecode)?
Does anyone know the tools the jQuery team uses (or at least in which format the documentation originally is)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: *"However, I do not want to put my documentation into the sourcecode and thereby making finding the correct lines while debugging impossible."* Say what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools are available for documenting jQuery plugins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639234/what-tools-are-available-for-documenting-jquery-plugins)

Comment: Agreed 110% with @T.J. **In no way** does adding comments to JS source code make it harder to "find the correct lines while debugging."

Comment: Well - I already **do have** problems of navigating in my files (without them containing documentation). My plugin if far from completition and has more than 1000 LOC. In C#/Java I would split it into multiple files and add the documentation to the sourcecode. However, this is no option in JavaScript. And it's not only while debugging: When reading through code, documentation annotations IMHO only distract from the actual code.

Comment: @Matt Ball: No duplicate; linked question's accepted solution points to a tool which "scans your code and builds high-quality HTML documentation from it." <-- Not what I want.

Comment: @winSharp93: A far, far cry from making finding the correctly lines while debugging "impossible," then. ;-) Any decent debugger (like the ones built into most browsers these days) will make it nearly impossible *not* to, what with highlighting the current line in step-by-step mode. At merely 1,000 LOC, I'm not seeing a problem, I find the search feature of programming editors entirely up to the task. Agree about this not being a duplicate, btw., although it looks like [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) (the accepted answer there) may have an external-files solution for you.

Comment: Agreed - "impossible" was certainly a bit too strong :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org) provides for documentation in [external files](http://www.naturaldocs.org/documenting/reference.html#TextFiles) (as well as in the source code).

<s>The tool that the Prototype team use for documenting Prototype, PDoc, works purely from comments. *(The link died, so I removed it.)* So you could have .js files that were purely the PDoc comments for your plug-in.</s> *2015: As far as I can tell, PDoc is dead.*

I'd advocate having the comments *in* the source code — classic maintenance issue having them separated — but if you're set on not doing that, fair 'nuff, both of those seem to be options for you.

Comment: Thanks - looks like a possibility where I can even switch to inline-documentetion (and back) without too much effort.

Comment: @winSharp93: Yeah, exactly -- in both cases. Quite cool, really.

Comment: This is from quite a while ago, but PDoc link seems to be dead/pointed to a spammer now.

Comment: @D_N: Thanks, and LOL - I have no time for GoDaddy, but I wouldn't call them *spammers*. I'll remove the dead link. I'm not at all surprised that project went belly-up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Too bad, though! I was hoping for something different.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not agree that adding documentation to source code can make it harder to find the correct lines during debug, I appreciate the sentiment that certain styles of documentation can be verbose and a bit of an eye sore while trying to just "get into the code."

I really like the approach taken by the folks behind underscore.js and backbone.js in their 'annotated source' documentation.

For example, check out the [underscore annotated source here](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html).  This documentation was generated based in-line comments, as seen in their [source on GitHub](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js).  But notice this is not the heavy, multi-line documentation style favoring verbosity over brevity.  I realize you asked for out-of-file documentation, but I submit this to you as a potential solution to your problem.

You can generate this type of documentation with [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/), which also includes links to Ruby, Python, and even shell script implementations.

Comment: Not directly what I am looking for, but surely handy for code-examples. Thanks - I won't use it for this problem, but at some other point.

Answer (score -1):

have you looked into [jsdoc](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)?

> JsDoc Toolkit is an application,
>   written in JavaScript, for
>   automatically generating
>   template-formatted, multi-page HTML
>   (or XML, JSON, or any other
>   text-based) documentation from
>   commented JavaScript source code.

Comment: "documentation from commented JavaScript source code" <-- Again, not what I want to have ;-)